# Transform Schema Struct

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How to transform that [header: struct<technical: struct<eventTechId: string, eventNormVersion: string ... 7 more fields>, functional: struct<eventType: struct<OEId: string, version: string>, eventorigin: struct<brand: string, organizationalEntity: struct<ITRId: string, OEID: string>> ... 6 more fields>>, payload: map<string,string>] to  [header: struct<eventTechId: string, eventNormVersion: string ... 17 more fields>, payload: map<string,string>]

in spark scala

[header: struct<eventTechId: string, eventNormVersion: string ... 17 more fields>, payload: map<string,string>]